# When I open blender, my textures and materials turn bright pink?

Tags: rendering

When I open blender, the textures and materials I used turn bright pink. Does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that Blender can't find your textures. So you either moved or deleted these textures. Simply relocate your textures for your material and it will look like normal. You can pack all of the external data (images, sound files, video files and appended data) into your blend file but this will heavily increase the size of it, to do this: *File> External Data> Pack all*.

Comment: Does this mean that every time my textures turn pink, I have to relocate my textures?

Comment: Yes, this is why its best to have a texture library that doesn't get moved.

Comment: No worries, glad I helped